# don't want dynamically module generate in home page

Tags: angular

I am new in angular here the problem is I have dynamic module. when I run my project all modules will generate. But I don't want to generate all modules I want only generate login page module that I have. below I am sharing screen short and share the app.routing.ts page code.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules  } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AddphyComponent } from './addphy/addphy/addphy.component';


export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login/dev', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  { path:'login', redirectTo:'login/local', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'login/dev', loadChildren: 'app/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'login/local', loadChildren: 'app/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: 'app/pages/register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
  { path: 'forgotpwd', loadChildren: 'app/pages/forgotpwd/forgotpwd.module#ForgotPwdModule' },
  { path: 'addphy', component: AddphyComponent },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    useHash: true
});
```

[image]

Comment: You can use lazy loading in module..so only require module will load on page..Check tutorial here https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

from Angular [`PreloadAllModules`](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules) Documentations:

> Provides a preloading strategy that preloads all modules as quickly as possible.

Just configure routes like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please accept the answer if it solves your issue.